# What happened to the equality in this probability equation?

Tags: probability, statistics

The problem states: if a certain event has not occurred in 2 hours what is the probability it will happen in the next hour?

The solution says:

$$P(2<X<3| X>2)={P(2<X<3 \cap X>2)\over P(X>2)}$$
$$={P(2<X<3)\over P(X>2)}$$

What happened to $X>2$?

Is it gone because that is already included in the $2<X<3$ statement?

Comment: Yes. If $2<X<3$ then you can be certain $X > 2$

Comment: Yes. Both sentences must happen at the same time. But if $2<X<3$, in particular, $2<X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. If $2<X<3$ then you can be certain $X > 2$

To take a slightly different example: $$P(4<X<6\mid X>5) = \dfrac{P(5<X<6)}{P(X>5)}$$ because the intersection of the event $4<X<6$ with the event $X>5$ is the event $5<X<6$